# SQLcl Nashorn js missing on upgrade?

Tags: java, oracle, nashorn, sqlcl

Recently upgraded to SQL Developer
21.4.3.063.0100 on Java 1.8.0_311 from 18.1.0.095.1630 on Java 1.8.0_152

And now all scripts running through the sqlcl component fail on startup

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


SQLcl: Release 21.4 Production on Thu Jun 09 14:21:56 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle. All rights reserved.

!ScriptCommand.1!!ScriptCommand.1!js language engine not found
Please add js language engine to the classpath
SQL> show java
Java Detail
-----------
java.home= C:\Program Files\SQL Developer 21.4.3\jdk\jre
java.vendor= Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url= http://java.oracle.com/
java.version= 1.8.0_311
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
os.arch= amd64
os.name= Windows 10
os.version= 10.0

SQL> version
Oracle SQLDeveloper Command-Line (SQLcl) version: 21.4.2.0 build: 21.4.2.59.1646
```

Command line used to start up sqlcl instance:

```
%COMSPEC% /Q /C SET SQLPATH=%CD%&SET /P JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=<utf8.txt&C:\Program Files\SQL Developer\sqldeveloper\bin\sql.exe" /nolog
```

My login.sql file does run js scripts to automatically manage connections

What is the resolution for this?

Noting I’ve seen stuff about Nashorn being deprecated; would that be the cause?  If it’s deprecated is there a replacement?  I’ve a lot setup on it.

Comment: See here - https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2022/04/running-javascript-in-oracle-sqlcl-22-1/

Comment: Using GraalVM is one option but Nashorn has been open sourced. I imagine you could just add it to your environment although I don't know what steps are needed. https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn/